# Manda Confirmação de Email

Tags: php

```
<?php

$email = $_POST['email'];

$result_leados = "INSERT INTO tb_usuarios email VALUES ('$email')";
$resultado_leados = mysql_query($con, $result_leados);

    //Inicio Enviar e-mail
        require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

        $Mailer = new PHPMailer();

        //Define que será usado SMTP
        $Mailer->IsSMTP();

        //Enviar e-mail em HTML
        $Mailer->isHTML(true);

        //Aceitar carasteres especiais
        $Mailer->Charset = 'UTF-8';

        //Configurações
        $Mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
        $Mailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

        //nome do servidor
        $Mailer->Host = 'localhost';
        //Porta de saida de e-mail 
        $Mailer->Port = 465;

        //Dados do e-mail de saida - autenticação
        $Mailer->Username = 'controla.estoque2018@gmail.com';
        $Mailer->Password = 'modercontrol';

        //E-mail remetente (deve ser o mesmo de quem fez a autenticação)
        $Mailer->From = 'controla.estoque2018@gmail.com';

        //Nome do Remetente
        $Mailer->FromName = 'Controla estoque';

        //Assunto da mensagem
        $Mailer->Subject = 'Titulo - Confirmação de email;'

        //Corpo da Mensagem
        $mensagem = "Olá <br><br>";
        $mensagem .= "Confirme seu e-mail acessar o sistema, após isso execute o login. <br> <br>";
        $mensagem .= "Clique aqui para confirmar seu e-mail</a><br> <br>";
        $mensagem .= "Se você recebeu este e-mail por engano, simplesmente o exclua.<br> <br>";
        $mensagem .= "Controla estoque";

        $Mailer->Body = $mensagem;

        //Corpo da mensagem em texto
        $Mailer->AltBody = 'conteudo do E-mail em texto';

        //Destinatario 
        $Mailer->AddAddress($email);

        if($Mailer->Send()){
            echo "E-mail enviado com sucesso";
        }else{
            echo "Erro no envio do e-mail: " . $Mailer->ErrorInfo;
        }

        //Fim Enviar e-mail

if(mysql_affected_rows($con) != 0){
            echo "
                <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=http://localhost/Aula/cadastrando.php'>
                <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert(\"E-mail recebido com Sucesso.\");
                </script>
            ";  
        }else{
            echo "
                <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=http://localhost/Aula/cadastrando.php'>
                <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert(\"Falha no cadastro do e-mail.\");
                </script>
            ";  
        }?>
?>
```

Erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$mensagem' (T_VARIABLE) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Controla\cadastrando.php on line 106

está dando esse erro quando tentou compilar o código eu queria saber o porque não está enviando a mensagem pro email, pois eu sou iniciante no php

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$mensagem' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Controla\cadastrando.php on line 106

Comment: está dando esse erro quando tentou compilar o código eu queria saber o porque não está enviando a mensagem pro email, pois eu sou iniciante no php.

Answer (score 0):

O erro está na linha:

```
$Mailer->Subject = 'Titulo - Confirmação de email;'
```

O ponto-e-vírgula está fora de lugar. O correto seria:

```
$Mailer->Subject = 'Titulo - Confirmação de email';
```

Como a linha de código não foi fechada, a variável `$mensagem` na linha seguinte seria uma continuação, causando o erro de sintaxe `unexpected '$mensagem' (T_VARIABLE)`.

Comment: Agora dá este erro aqui : Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Controla\cadastrando.php on line 67
Erro no envio do e-mail: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting ?>

Comment: Isso é um erro de conexão com o banco de dados. Como esse erro não está relacionado à pergunta, você pode fazer uma nova pergunta para obter ajuda específica ao problema ou pesquisar para ver se já não existe uma pergunta relacionada.